# How to keep a forceNetwork {networkD3} centered in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, networkd3

While building a Shiny app that displays a forceNetwork graph, the network does not stay centered but moves out of view when one interactively changes the opacity.

My question is, how to change this behavior and keep the network nicely centered as it was initially?

A reproducible example:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

shinyUI(fluidPage( 

      titlePanel("ForceNetD3"), 

      sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
               sliderInput("opacity",
                      "Opacity",
                       min = 0.1,
                       max = 1,
                       value = 0.4)
      ),
      mainPanel(
            forceNetworkOutput(outputId = "net")
      )
)))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

       # Load data
       data(MisLinks)
       data(MisNodes)      

       output$net <- renderForceNetwork(forceNetwork(
                          Links  = MisLinks, Nodes   = MisNodes,
                          Source = "source", Target  = "target",
                          Value  = "value",  NodeID  = "name",
                          Group  = "group",  opacity = input$opacity))
})
```

The behavior in pictures:

[image]
[image]
Annndd... it's gone:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the timer in d3.force() is running out, and it isn't "reheated" when new values are input. Without changes to networkD3, you can hack this to work by adding `colourScale = JS('force.alpha(1); force.restart(); d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);')` to your arguments in your `forceNetwork()` function. So you would have for `server.R`...

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

       # Load data
       data(MisLinks)
       data(MisNodes)      

       output$net <- renderForceNetwork(forceNetwork(
                          Links  = MisLinks, Nodes   = MisNodes,
                          Source = "source", Target  = "target",
                          Value  = "value",  NodeID  = "name",
                          Group  = "group",  opacity = input$opacity,
                          colourScale = JS('force.alpha(1); force.restart(); d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);')))
})
```

**UPDATE (2017.03.20)**

This issue has been resolved in the most recent released version (0.4) of networkD3, and what the OP is asking for is the default behavior.

Comment: Your solution works. Are there any other solutions you can suggest? And would you agree that the default behavior is undesirable?

Comment: You could theoretically insert the JavaScript commands on one of the other forceNetwork arguments that get evaluated. If shiny has a way of evaluating/running some JavaScript code whenever an input changes, that would probably work as well. I wouldn't say the default behavior is wrong, it just wasn't designed with this purpose in mind. If you care to, you could open a new issue at https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues and maybe we'll get to it eventually.

Comment: So now every time `input$opacity` changes the graph is "thrown" again from upper left corner to the center... Is there a way to use your `colourScale`-`JS` hack to keep the root node (or any node) centered?

Comment: Not that I know of... the d3.force simulation has to "start" from somewhere. As it's currently setup, any time a change is made shiny re-renders the plot.

Comment: If you could tell shiny to run some JavaScript on the page and *not* rerender the plot, then you could change the opacity of the nodes with JavaScript and not affect anything else, but I don't know enough about shiny to know if that's possible. Your script currently tells shiny to rerender the plot with a new set of parameters every time you change the opacity input, which is why you get the current behavior.