# networkD3 simpleNetwork not re-rendering properly in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, networkd3

I'm looking to render and re-render a simpleNetwork graph based on clicking an actionButton . However, for some reason, clicking the button multiple times does not create a new simpleNetwork instance, but rather seems to use a cached version. How do I get simpleNetwork graphs to re-render entirely on multiple clicks?

I've included an example below as well as a gif of the issue:

[.gif of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF7Y5.gif)

```html
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- eventReactive(input$click, {
    src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
    target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
    networkData <- data.frame(src, target)
  })
  
  output$simple <- renderSimpleNetwork({
    simpleNetwork(data())
  })
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("networkD3 + Shiny"),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(actionButton("click", "Render")),
                  
                  mainPanel(simpleNetworkOutput(
                    "simple", width = "100%", height = "700px"
                  ))
                ))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was already reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42764760/how-to-keep-a-forcenetwork-networkd3-centered-in-a-shiny-app/42767469#42767469). It was fixed with [PR #179](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/pull/179) and released in [version 0.4 on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=networkD3). Make sure your networkD3 package is updated.